# Make Aquamacs' windows zoom like ordinary Mac apps?

Tags: window-manager, emacs

When I double-click on a window in Aquamacs, it keeps the same width but maximises its height.  A second double-click maximises the width as well.  A third double-click returns it to its original size and position.

I would like to tell Aquamacs (http://aquamacs.org) to act more like an ordinary Mac app, so the intermediate step with the height is omitted, and a second double-click will restore the window to the original size.

A sort of work around is to use the green button at the top left of the window, taking the window to its own space, which is usually not ideal.

I can write Emacs Lisp routines to manipulate windows (a.k.a. "frames" in Aquamacs and Emacs), but I don't know how to get Emacs to run my elisp routine on the title bar double click.

Unlike a lot of user actions in Aquamacs, typing control-H control-K before the double click does not give me help on the action.  So I have done some searching on the net and in the Aquamacs help.  I have looked through the Preferences, options, and Customise as well.  Having said that, there are a lot of things there, and I may have missed the answer.

I suspect a solution will be in the C or Objective-C source code rather than the elisp code.  I suppose I can hunt through the source code to find out how to change this, but I hope I can ask for help at Ask Different.

I have Aquamacs 3.2 and macOS Sierra 10.2.3.  I've also tried on some different Macs with slight version variations.

Comment: Did you try http://aquamacs.org/support.html, especially the mailing list mentioned there?

Comment: Thanks @patrix!  Yes, I visited the support page.  This afternoon I started searching through the github repo, the source, the change log, and the mailing list.  One discovery I have made is that the feature existed as far back as version 2.5.  That narrows it down.

Comment: I was more thinking about sending a mail into the mailing list there

Comment: @patrix, good idea, but I want to make sure I've done enough research before I ask.  (I may be overdoing this research. :-)  Meanwhile, I've found that version 0.9.1 only zooms the height.

Comment: FYI, this behavior is also present in vanilla GNU Emacs 25.1.1, so it does not appear to be specific to Aquamacs.

Comment: Thanks @GDP2 for a crucial comment! After some investigation I am starting to think this is off topic as an Emacs question rather than an Apple question.  I'm thinking of deleting the question, but I haven't decided.  I am continuing investigating.

Comment: In my last comment, please replace _this is off topic_ with _my question is off topic_.  @GDP2's comment is right on topic!

Comment: @DAVincent No problem. If you find a fix for this, please let it be known here as this is actually an interesting issue and I've rummaged a bit through the C / Obj-C source but haven't found the responsible code yet.